# Undeclare variable 'event' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, declare

Quite often I have problems with TypeScript and using a parameter called `event` for referring to the event.

The problem is that when I use it in a method, but forget to declare it as input parameter, see:

```
addItem = () =>
{
    var popup = new Popup();

    popup.show( event ); // this function i.e. needs a default click event forwarded
}
```

All works well in Chrome - my preferable browser for development - but then I discover problems with Firefox after deployment.

The problem is `event` is available in the global scope in Chrome, and also defined like this in the default typescript **lib.d.ts** file.

For 99.99% of the times I don't want to use the `event` in the global scope - I see this as an anti-pattern.

Can I undeclare a global variable in TypeScript?

- I don't want to change the lib.d.ts because I need to fix this in all environments I ever work on
- I could of course default to using a different name for this parameter, i.e. evt, but I just prefer to use the most descriptive name

Answer (score 2):

While you can augment any interface, including `Window`, you cannot alter the types of pre-existing fields. E.g., this doesn't work:

```
interface Window {
    event: never; // Error: redeclarations must have the same type
}
```

If your codebase is suited to enable `strictNullChecks`, then using the global `event` property will fail as its type is declared as `Event | undefined`.

So, with strictNullChecks enabled, this will error:

```
document.onload = () => {
    console.info(event.target); // Error: event can be undefined
};
```

A named event parameter on the handler will not have `undefined` in its type and this error may give you the hint to add the parameter.

But if you cannot enable strictNullChecks, there is no way to force it.

[TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) may add a rule to ban these globals soon, see [the current PR](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/3824), that would at least catch this in a linting phase.

Comment: Here's a relevant typescript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14306

Comment: Also eslint has `no-restricted-globals` rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals